# Is Apples Objective-C++ 2.0 compiler available (and useable) on other platforms?

Tags: objective-c++

I know it's part of gcc but is it useable on Windows? The (core) runtime with its garbage collector does seem to be pretty complicated to port so i doubt it will be portable by coincidence. I don't want any Cocoa stuff just the pure metal basic support.

What about other unix versions Solaris/FreeBSD/AIX/HP-UX ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see this question: [Objective C for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)

You may need to use GNUStep or another system in order to have the garbage collection work. You don't have to use garbage collection in Obj C 2.0 alternatively.