# Objective-C and Windows

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ide

I am currently in a class that is developing applications in Objective-C and Cocoa. I was wondering if there was any way to build and compile Objective-C applications on Windows Vista. During class, we are able to use the Mac machines provided to us, but I was hoping to do some work outside of class, and I only have a Windows Vista machine available to me. I have installed GNUStep. I am looking for a GUI or an IDE that I could use. I have Eclipse, and I tried to install ObjectivEClipse, but that is only for a Mac machine too. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows (with a practically identical title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNUstep itself offers [ProjectCenter](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/ProjectCenter.html), which is a take-off of Project Builder, the NeXTstep IDE that Xcode is derived from. It also maintains the Interface Builder knockoff [GORM](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Gorm.html).

Also, you'll want to bear in mind that GNUstep is a bit limited compared to Cocoa (just because Apple has a whole paid professional development team working on Cocoa full-time and GNUstep does not) and GORM uses a different format from Interface Builder, so if you're taking a class, there may be some Cocoa assignments you won't be able to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is no problem, since gcc includes an Objectve-C frontend.  You could simply install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and use it.  the issue is about libraries.

The Cocoa system is very Apple proprietary; but it's a descendant from NeXTStep. For a while (when NeXT was even deeper in debts than Apple) it was named OpenStep, and available as a shell around the NT kernel.  Around that time, the [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/) project was started, and it seems it's still there.

Note, however, that any xxStep libraries gives only a NeXT-like GUI, very different from modern macs.  Also, a lot of the newer capabilities are not only new GUI; but new APIs too and these won't be found there.

in short... it's easier to go with a mac.

Answer (score 1):

Under the heading of desperation measures:

It's old school but if you have a friend with a mac, you could telnet into the mac and run the dev tools there. You would code in an editor on Vista and then up load to the mac to compile.

That would only let you see the results of command line apps but it would better than nothing.

If the macs in your school lab are accessible you could just screen share from your Vista box. That's another long shot.

Might be easier to beg, borrow or steal a Mac mini.

Answer (score 0):

The Cocoa frameworks are only available on Mac.  For anything else, you'll have to use GNUStep.