# Is it possible to execute Objective-C programs in Windows?

Tags: objective-c, windows

I googled a lot. Some people are saying do this. Some are saying it's not possible. Install Mac OS X on a virtual machine, etc., etc.

I have a simple question.
**Is it possible that I can practice [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) programming on a Windows 7 machine?**

If yes, how? Please, if possible, provide me with a necessary link. My ultimate goal is to go for [iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone) development. But right now I can't afford a [MacBook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook).

So is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Objective-C for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Objective-C, the language, definitely yes.  At the very least, GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) compiles Objective-C just fine.  You can get either Cygwin for the full POSIX-like environment, or MinGW which gives just the GNU toolchain for programming to the Win23 API

But, iPhone needs the Apple API, which is totally proprietary; if they say 'No Windows', then it's just not available for Windows

Of course the iPhone API is based on Cocoa, which is based on NextSTEP.  You can get the feel of the API with OpenSTEP.

But it's not iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can compile Objective-C on Windows. But for iPhone development [this question was already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows).

And there are several similar questions about iPhone development here on Stackoverflow, just search for it.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth taking a look at Cocotron— that aims to implement a cross-platform Apple-compatible version of the core NeXTStep libraries, the FoundationKit and ApplicationKit. Windows included.

Answer (score 1):

GCC (http://gcc.gnu.org/) can compile Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, but it will probably require quite a lot of work on your part:

www.gnustep.org
www.cocotron.org

Answer (score 0):

This page on StackOverflow, answer 4. It worked great in my case.

[Objective C for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows?rq=1)