# I need a windows objective-c programming IDE that checks syntax and warns errors

Tags: objective-c, syntax, ide

I need a programming IDE for windows and objective-c.  It doesn't need to compile and run or anything like that, but I really need it to check my code, and make sure it's legitimate.

After hours of searching I haven't found anything good...

Comment: You can use Cygwin or MinGW.  See the answer at:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903869/is-it-possible-to-execute-objective-c-programs-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JetBrain is one and there was a failed eclipse objective c project. Or you could use X-code on a virtual Machine

Comment: I really just ended up forgetting the idea of helping my team width ios, and just decided to develop what we were working on for android, so, unfortunately I no longer need it, but thanks anyway