# Cocoa Programming on Windows

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, windows

Is there a way to develop windows applications using cocoa and objective-c in general

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows

Comment: that was for objective-c, i want to know for cocoa as well

Comment: It's clear however that Apple have ported cocoa to windows for developing apple-branded apps; since Safari and iTunes are both cocoa apps.

Comment: iTunes is most certainly not a Cocoa application.

Comment: Neither is Safari for Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, Cocoa is specific to Mac OSX. But you might have a look at [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/).

For Objective-C, you might want to have a look at [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/).

Answer (score 13):

To be clear, Objective-C is to Cocoa as C# is to .NET, or even as the Java language is to the Java platform — it's the primary way of doing things. Objective-C can be used wherever the compiler supports it, but the Cocoa frameworks are really the most valuable part of the equation.

One should also note that (os OS X) Safari is a Cocoa app, but iTunes is not yet (it still uses the legacy Carbon APIs) so I'm not sure how it is on Windows. Apple has ported some significant parts of Cocoa to Windows DLL's to port Safari, but to my knowledge, that code is not available for public consumption. (One can imagine that Apple doesn't really want to make it easy to create robust apps for a competing OS, they have only published two key apps to further their own goals, like adoption of iPod/iTunes and the WebKit browser core.) Don't expect to see these Cococa-Windows libraries become widely available; if they do, it will be a surprise to many of us.

As @Gregory mentioned, GNUStep and Cocotron are plausible options to explore, but I'd suggest thinking long and hard about whether you really should do what you're asking. By and large, Microsoft's tools have much better support for Windows, you'll run into fewer undocumented limitations, and their native apps will tend to "feel right" to Windows users. I learned some time back that although I *love* Objective-C/Cocoa, if I ever *had* to write a Windows program, I would do it with the C#/.NET platform.

Comment: very comprehensive, i agree with your point on writing apps for a specific platform using tools meant for that platform. But its a pain for developers to shift track completely after they have spent a considerable amount of their time mastering a particular technology

Comment: If I want to build cross-platform apps, Cocoa on Windows and Linux would be an ideal solution.  Telling me to use .NET doesn't really solve the problem: it only addresses the Windows part.  (Yes I know about mono, but I and probably many others would much rather build apps that are perfect on OS X, and cut corners on OSs where people don't care so much about aesthetic details.)