# Is it possible to code Objective-C on Windows?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to test Objective-C, but I don't have a Mac. Is it possible to program Objective-C in Windows? Another possibility is to do it in Linux. Does anyone know if either is possible?

Comment: Previously asked and answered in more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the **GNU Compiler Collection** contains an Objective-C frontend.

It will easily work on Linux and can be used on Windows too if you workaround with some binary distributions like cygwin or gnustep.

But I don't think you will have any kind of Cocoa API, you will have just the ObjC syntax.

Comment: GNUStep is an open source version of the Cocoa API.

Comment: thanks for your clarification. Never got too deep inside ObjC on other platforms since I've got a mac :)