# objective-c tags file for vim

Tags: objective-c, vim, tags, vi

I'd like to use Vim for editing sources and Xcode for all other purposes like managing, debugging etc. I've installed cocoa.vim plugin and it helps with highlighting, but I still need a way to navigate around the code. In java project I used ctags for the purpose, but it doesn't support obj-c.

So the question is: what is the easiest way to generate vi-compatible tags file for Objective-C sources?

Comment: It seems that you might find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968522/alternatives-to-ctags-cscope-with-objective-c , This link too http://www.gregsexton.org/2011/04/objective-c-exuberant-ctags-regex/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of the second link that jelera pointed to and must say it is now out of date.

I would follow the advice in the accepted answer of [Alternatives to Ctags/Cscope with Objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968522/alternatives-to-ctags-cscope-with-objective-c) in order to get full Obj-C parser support in ctags.

If you use tagbar, this post will help get the new ctags binary working with it:

http://bastibe.de/2011-12-04-how-to-make-tagbar-work-with-objective-c.html

This is pretty much the setup I now use.

Comment: The second link is dead unfortunately. Can you either find a cached version or remove it please ?

Comment: @Max Try [this blog post](http://bastibe.de/posts/How-to-make-Tagbar-work-with-Objective-C.html). Also, from this [Github repo](https://github.com/dlitz/vimfiles/blob/master/vimrc#L193) it seems that the blog post had a objective C definition for tagbar which you can see my link.