# Objective C on Windows or Linux

Tags: objective-c, windows, linux, compiler-construction

I would like to learn objective-c, but don't have a Mac.

How would I compile obj-c on Windows or Linux?
*I would prefer Windows, but Linux would be OK.*

Comment: See [Objective C for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC has an objective-C compiler. You may also want to investigate the [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/) tools, which provide a clone of the OpenStep APIs (Which Cocoa is based on.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use gcc to compile objective c as suggested by the previous answers. But one thing is if you are planning this for iPhone development then mac is a must as the framework, simulator etc. are not available in other platforms.

Comment: The iPhone dev tools (the toolchain used for developing for jailbroken phones) are intended to run on Linux.

Comment: all development tools like interface builder, instrument also available? and what is the latest sdk that can be used? and another thing is it possible to make adhoc (intended to run on device that is not jailbroken) or app store submission build? personally im a linux fan and would be happy if i could use it for iphone development.

Answer (score 1):

http://gnustep.org/ -- no experience using it, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to experiment, there's an Objective-C compiler for .NET (Windows) here: http://www.qckapp.com/index.html?p=ObjC