# Windows development using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, windows

Having recently read up a on Objective-C it strikes me as a fairly neat language with plenty of cool features.

I have no intention of doing any iPhone development, however I understand that GCC is able to compile Objective-C code and so I wanted to know - **Is Objective-C a viable alternative language to C99 for Windows development?**

In particular:

- Is anyone currently doing Windows development using Objective-C?
- Are there any runtime components that would need to be distributed with my applications?
- I understand that Objective-C is a superset of C, does this mean that it is possible to use any C-compatible library? (for example the Windows API)
- Would I get garbage collection in my applications?
- I've found [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/) and [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/) which are often mentioned when talking about using Objective-C on other platforms, however as GCC can already be used to compile Objective-C I don't really understand why I would need these.
- Are there any other pitfalls or traps I might run in attempting Windows development using Objective-C?

Comment: I've found the question [Objective C for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows) which is interesting, however doesn't really answer my questions about viability, runtime components or really any of the bulleted points in the question.

Comment: To get the maximum benefit of Objective C like you see in Mac environments, then you need to use the Cocoa libraries. Else its just looks like a language which supports object-orientation on top of C. You merely get the language's in-built features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With respect to your first question, I don't know if anyone is **seriously** doing development on windows with Objective-C, but there may be, though those numbers would probably be less than those doing serious work with a language like [whitespace](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/).

Secondly, you would need, at a minimum the objective-c runtime. There are two runtimes, NeXT's (now Apple's) runtime, and the GNU Objective-C runtime. They are not compatible. If you are on a non-NeXT and non-Apple platform, such as windows, you have no choice, GNU runtime only.

Objective-C is a superset of C, and yes you can use the Win32 API if you so desire directly in your objective-c code. As well, you would only get garbage collection if you use a conservative collector, and it ties in with the libraries you're using. In short: No.

What GCC has is support for the objective-c language, and runtime, no standard library. What the GNU objc runtime provides you with in terms of a standard library, is two objects: Object, and NXConstantString class, which is needed to support the `@""` syntax. `Object` is merely a base class. Not very useful, eh? This is why frameworks like Cocotron and GNUstep exist — to give you access to an implementation of OPENSTEP/Cocoa.

Regarding pitfalls or traps, yeah: Your application, even using Cocotron or GNUstep may never be portable to the Mac for instance, or you may get bit by things like typed selectors in the GNU objc runtime, or a plethora of other problems. Let me finish answering this by posing another question: What pitfalls or traps might you run into targeting .NET? I'm sure some if not most of those apply in this case too. Standard pitfalls and traps apply.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was going to post this, but you beat me to it. +1 for capturing the main idea: Objective-C is useless without the runtime libraries, which is what Cocotron and GNUStep provide. However, they're not really feasible to use in any serious programs, and are quite behind Apple's runtime libraries. In short, there's no real use for Objective-C beyond the Mac and iPhone with Apple's runtime libraries.

Comment: @Kragen Without the runtime libraries, Objective-C can't do anything. Much of Objective-C depends on doing things at runtime (besides the necessary frameworks: Foundation, CoreFoundation, AppKit), and without the necessary libraries, it's ineffective. To use your example, it's like C without any libraries at all. If you want to do anything, you're going to have to implement it yourself (something you can't really do with Objective-C).

Comment: The GNU runtime is no longer the only alternative - there's now libobjc2, which supports pretty much anything that the Apple runtime does. The GNUStep libraries are still lagging, especially for UI stuff, but the core of the language is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mature solution yet. If you develop the solution itself, you can do it anyway. But if you're not, it's not the time.

For compiler tools, there is LLVM/Clang which are open-source under BSD license.
The compiler is sponsored by Apple, so it compiles Objective-C completely, and is becoming primary compiler for Apple. So compiler is no problem anymore.

Problem is runtime environment library. Objective-C language is depends it's runtime to execute. The runtime defines all behavior of object system and some more. Runtime environment library is core system and different with framework library like Cocoa or Quartz. in .NET, it's CRE, not .NET framework class library.
Without runtime, program cannot be executed like .NET program executed on Windows without .NET runtime.

For more details, check this conversation:
http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2010-January/007593.html