# Objective C editor for windows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, windows, editor

I need to review the iphone application code written by my colleague, but unfortunately I have only a windows PC at present.

It would be nice if some one suggest a tool like 'source insight' which can be used to navigate through the obj-c code in a windows environment.

Regards,
Dhanesh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the way to do what you want

[Installing and using GNUstep and Objective-C on Windows](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_and_using_GNUstep_and_Objective-C_on_Windows)

also for cross platform

http://www.cocotron.org/Info/

try this it is awesome.

Comment: Did you check the requirements?  The developer tools are designed to run from Xcode and the editor is therefore the Xcode editor.  Not down voting because although it doesn't answer the question, it is a useful link.

Comment: The Cocotron link looks like it will be really useful for one of my projects.  Unfortunately, the GNUStep idea might not be so useful.  I suggested it in answer to a similar question and the questioner came back with feedback that it was quite flakey on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try Notepad++, it seems to recognize Objective-C syntax.

Comment: I do a lot of objective-c work in NPP, if you don't need to navigate code it can work OK. It is very lightweight and I usually have it which saves me from having to install something else.