# iPhone/iPad export Eclipse Plug-ins

Tags: iphone, objective-c, eclipse, plugins

I was wondering are there any Eclipse plug-ins will that let me export my files (already packaged in the iPhone/iPad format) so that I can send to Apple for review. I don't have a Mac so XCode is out of the question.

I already have a plug-in to work in Objective-C, I just need a plug-in to export in iPhone/iPad format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you can conceivably compile Objective-C from Eclipse, you don't have the Cocoa Touch, Foundation, or any other libraries that will be required to build a functional iOS app.  You won't have a simulator.  You won't have any way to codesign and build/compile your apps for the hardware.  You won't have the tool to submit them.

You'll find a number of folks who have attempted to go down this road before - it's a dead end.  The easiest / cheapest solution is to buy a used Mac Mini and hook it up to your currently owned accessories (monitor, keyboard, mouse).

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck my friend, Apple uses Application Loader (a mac application) to upload the files to iTunes Connect.

Comment: well I might have to browow a Mac to upload it but what about exporting it from Eclipse?

Comment: @Benny I believe you would need some version of gcc to compile any objective-c code, this post may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows