# How do i use BIGNUM's from the openSSL module in Lazarus

Tags: delphi, openssl, pascal, lazarus, bignum

Background:I am working on an encryption application, i have the app written in Objective C and now i want to rewrite it in pascal so that it runs on windows. I am using pascal as it is a language i already know and lazarus as it is a free IDE

Question:
How do i use the BigNum module from openSSL in lazarus, i have downloaded this unit: http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/packages/openssl/src/

and i've put it in 
`uses openssl;`

However when i try and declare a BIGNUM

```
procedure Tform3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var bits:integer;
    p:BIGNUM;
begin
   bits:=512;

   p:=BN_new();
   BN_generate_prime(p, bits, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

end;
```

I just get an error: Error: Identifier not found "BIGNUM"

How do i use the BigNum module and the BN_generate prime(module)?

Comment: The code you link to does not include a type called `BIGNUM`. There is one called `PBIGNUM`. There is no function `BN_new` and no function `BN_generate prime`. Since you have the source yourself, you could have simply used the find facility of the IDE (or any text editor) to diagnose that yourself.

Comment: Thanks that answers the first part of my question but i still can't find a way of using BN_generate_prime or an equivalent.

Comment: Why don't you compile your objective C code on windows with mingw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows

Comment: @David: many of the good things for Objective-C are only available on the Apple platforms. I doubt they can be found in MingW's GNU Obj-C compiler.

Comment: @Rudy The encryption code would likely be fine

Comment: @David: Sure, but not the rest of the program.

Comment: @Rudy Well, link it in through a DLL or using $L. It was only the other day that you made the exact same recommendation!

Comment: @David: Much eaiser to use libeay32.dll, I guess. The openssl.pas file does not completely convert all functions.

Comment: And don't forget to submit a bug, or better a patch. Header improvements can probably still make the upcoming 2.6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unit you are using is an import unit for three DLLs, and one of them is *libeay32.dll*. But unfortunately, it does not fully import all functions from *libeay32.dll*. It omits, for instance, the `BIGNUM` part, i.e. what you are looking for.

Perhaps you can find a better import unit, like this unit called ***[libeay32.pas](http://www.disi.unige.it/person/FerranteM/delphiopenssl/libeay32.pas)***, which seems to have all the `BN_` functions or you can get the header from ***[this link](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html)*** and add the missing functions to *openssl.pas*. That is not trivial, but also not undoable. I would go for the ready translated unit. It looks good. The [website](http://www.disi.unige.it/person/FerranteM/delphiopenssl/) seems to have a few more things you might need.

Comment: The unit generates this error: 'libeay32.pas(275,5) Error: Compile time expression: Wanted STRING but got INTEGER at "COMPILERVERSION >= 20"' on line 275: '{$IF CompilerVersion >= 20}'

Comment: that's because you are using FreePascal rather than delphi. Just hack out enough of the unit to call the couple of functions you need.

Comment: @Tawfiqh: Probably the line can simply be commented out. Also comment out the $IFEND that belongs to it.

Comment: The decent way is to put it under {$ifndef FPC} if it tests Delphi specific conditionals (like versions). Don't forget to enable Delphi mode too

Comment: @Marco: sure, but that assumes the user of the unit actually knows the differences between Delphi and FPC and how they should be encountered.