# Objective C on Windows

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)

I know there are several posts about this but I don't feel that any of them fit my scenario. I  have been asked to learn Objective-C and write a report over its differences from C/C++ along with develop a presentation for my Programming Languages class. I would like to write a simple program using Objective-C but I do not have access to a Mac. I have a Windows machine and I am looking for an IDE that is not too complex (no need for source control or anything like that) but something that has a compiler (debugger is a plus). Any recommendations on what IDE to use for this? Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Gcc on Cygwin supports Objective C. There's no IDE though, just a command line compiler, and the run-time library is limited to that of Objective C itself - no Cocoa there.

Comment: If you're just trying to write a simple program, you probably don't need an IDE.  That'd be like using a crane to assemble Lincoln Logs.

Comment: Clang and QtCreator on Windows. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-tool-chains.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [GnuStep](http://www.gnustep.org/) which has an IDE called ProjectCenter. It is aimed at reproducing the NextStep/OpenStep programming experience on multiple platforms, including Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). It contains all the compilers from the GNU Compiler Collection, which includes also the objective-c compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Take at look at  [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/).
I personally never tested it, but it's supposed to suport AppKit, which is the UI Framework for Mac OS X.