# How to compile Objective C in windows7?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)

I am beginner of Objective C. I want to Learn this. How i can compile code on windows7? If any compiler help me, Please share with me :-)

Thnx
Ashu

Comment: [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows) and the next time use the search field in the upper right corner.

Comment: Adding links in comment is better rather than making it as answer.. +1 Ale

Comment: @InderKumarRathore yes you'r write.. Ashu firstly you search ur answer own labour, if not get, then share !