# way to create objective c program on another platform?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Is there any way to build objective c or iPhone program on Windows 7 ?

or any other software that is same as Xcode.

i does not want to deploy, want to build and test for learning purpose.

i don't want to install Mac OSx using VMware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get objective c compiler on your windows, but i dont think that you will be able to get the cocoa framework on it, so you could be able to learn objective c language but not cocao and cocoa touch

Some resources

- [Objective C for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)
- http://www.roseindia.net/iphone/objectivec/objective-c-windows.shtml

Comment: i want to use both the framework listed above then what should i do ?

Comment: read the articles, they will tell you how to install it on your machine

Comment: if you want to use cocoa and cocoa touch then you will need a mac or a vmware

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several solutions out there, but the first that comes to mind is [RareWire](http://rarewire.com). While you cannot design in objective-c, you can create iPhone apps on any platform that has a web-browser and send them to your device.

Unfortunately, at this time, RareWire is invite-only, so you would have to request an invite to get in.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for learning purposes with regards to the Objective-C language itself, meaning you don't need the Cocoa API, then gcc has a perfectly fine Objective-C compiler. See for yourself: http://ideone.com/395tl

Comment: i also want iphone simulator.