# Running objective c in windows

Tags: objective-c, windows, gnustep

I installed GNUstep and minGW. My code seems to compile without errors, when I try to run it I get:

> gnustep-base-1_24.dll is missing

I'm using Windows GNUStep.

Note: I added the GNUstep/system/Tools directory to my PATH

Comment: i hope this tutorial will help as it did with me: https://sweettutos.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/objective-c-on-windows-yes-you-can/

Comment: You also need to add `GNUstep/bin` directory to PATH. Restart the computer for sure and try again.

Answer (score 1):

this link is very helpful for set up GUNstep:
[objective-c-for-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)

But if there's something wrong when you compile, try this command:
gcc -o hello hello.m -I/c/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers \
-L /c/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base \
-fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString

Answer (score 1):

**For this problem** , you may solve it follow the advice below：

1. open Settings >> Compiler.. >> Global compiler settings >> Toolchain executables >> **Additional Paths**
2. add Path “X:\GNUstep\GNUstep\System\Tools”  where gnustep-base-1_24.dll  located

**Good Luck！**

base on *Code::Block 12.11*