# Can Objective-C be used for non-Apple programming?

Tags: objective-c

Java, C, C++ etc can be used for several types of computers and even mobile phones.

But, can Objective-C be used for anything except Apple products? Could I make an Objective-C program for a Windows machine (or linux), just like I do for java?

Comment: Linux, but not windows.  The CLI doesn't support Apple's libs, and vice-versa.

Comment: @CodaFi - i don't know what CLI means. Please tell me.

Comment: (Common Language Interface) but you didnt need to know that.  Just know that programming outside of apple's sphere of influence means you can use the language, but you lose the support, the tools, the community, and the compiler chain you've grown accustomed to.

Comment: @CodaFi - Can I also get some examples of commercial Objective C software written for other OSes/platforms ? Like this hypothetical example - 
Safari browser for Windows XP and above written in Objective C, CallOfDuty for Android - written in objective C etc ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)

Comment: @lnafziger - this is not related to the question, but you are a pilot and programmer !!! How did that happen ?

Comment: Haha, I've been programming for a long time, and took up flying as a hobby initially.  The more that I did it, the more I loved it, until one day I decided to make it my career.  I've never looked back!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This link should answer your question: [gnustep.org](http://gnustep.org).

In short:

> The purpose of this project is to create a free and open version of
>   the Cocoa (formerly known as NeXTSTEP/OpenStep) APIs and tools for as
>   many platforms as possible.

Comment: So  basically, if Gnu step ends up working well, then i will be able to make code for apple products only, using non-apple machines as well ?

Comment: This is Cocoa on windows.  You don't need Cocoa in order to program in Objective-C.

Comment: While you technically don't need Cocoa, there's not much you can do without it. Objective-C as a language lacks even basic data structures so unless you're going to be replicating that functionality, GNUStep is certainly the way to go.