# Objective-c in windows

Tags: objective-c, windows

Is there any way that I can learn and test objective-c in windows?
I am going to buy mac book but I really need to start learning Objective-c and testing it?
I will be pleased if you know anyway in making and running  Objective-c in windows, and inform me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)

Comment: I know but I need a step by step tutorial to how to run it on windows + IDE + how to compile and see result?

Comment: Did you try this? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXFdMGcboNg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective C for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use services like [macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) to work on a Mac in the cloud from your PC.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need mac os for using xcode.. maybe you can install mac os on your pc. check this website: http://www.hackintosh.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are many hacks available to run mac on windows for xcode or other purpose but you should not do this because of the following resosns

1. Its illegal.
2. It will not perform well.
3. Many of the drivers are not available for windows based machines.

Hackintosh is a solution but its like running windows 8 on pentium 3 with 256MB RAM

choice is yours

Answer (score 0):

Technically, compiling Objective-C on windows or even other OS is possible. 
But it might need a lot of efforts to make it work within some IDEs.

You should take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows).
You need stuffs like Cygwin, gcc to compile Objective-C on windows.

And you also should read this [HOWTO: Compiling Objective-C with gcc](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1064045).
Although it's for Ubuntu, but it gives you a piece of sample code to show you the difference, and tells you some tips.