# Objective C in Windows "cannot find -lgnustep-base"

Tags: objective-c, windows

This is my second question on using Objective C in Windows - but I can't seem to find a way to do it. This time I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9849288/2162730), but I got the result:

```
cannot find -lgnustep-base
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is your `-L` pointing to? Are you sure that's the folder with the `libgnustep-base` file?

Answer (score 3):

So you are using MinGW and need to know where it stores its libraries. This can vary with installations.

You could simply search for where the library libgnustep-base.a is on your system. If it is not too be found that would be the problem.  If it is in say /usr/Mingw/lib then add -L/usr/Mingw/lib to the compiler command line with -lgnustep-base in it.

Alternatively move it into the same lib folder as the other MinGW libraries that are found.