# Objective C Compiler for Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

Tags: objective-c, installation

I need help. I have Windows 7 Professional (64-bit), and I am starting to learn Objective C from a book. I want to somehow install a Objective C compiler on Windows and I followed this link:

[Objective C for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708/objective-c-for-windows)

But unfortunately it is not working. I tried exactly the way the answer was given and I am on the shell command prompt, but how do I find my `helloworld.exe` file? Where is it?

Comment: I got this working, I just follow the second answer line by line - what is the result of the compile operation?

Comment: I am so confused. I just see a shell kind of a type thing with $ sign. Is that the compiler for Objective C? Can you please email me: dilshad40@hotmail.com